# AngularFire2 ngrx/effects get document by id not working

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx-effects

How to get a document from a collection in firestore, using the document's id.

The snapshotChanges and valueChanges are available, but I'm getting undefined for the doc.data()

```
@Effect()
    queryDetails$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType(speakerActions.QUERY_DETAILS)
        .map((action: speakerActions.QueryDetails) => action.payload)
        .mergeMap(action => {
            const ref: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${action}`)
            return ref.snapshotChanges()
        })
        .map(snapshot => {
            if(snapshot.payload) {
                console.log(`SpeakerEffects :: queryDetails : ${snapshot.payload.id}`)
                return {
                    type: `[Speaker] modified`,
                    payload: { id: snapshot.payload.id, ...snapshot.payload.doc.data() }
                }
            }
        })
```

The 'User' object interface details are as below:

```
export class User {

    id: string;

    name: string;
    email: string;

    about: string;

    emailVerified?: boolean;

    reader: boolean;
    author?: boolean;
    admin?:  boolean;

    roles: Roles;

    loading?: boolean;

    constructor(authData) {
        this.id         = authData.uid
        this.email      = authData.email
        this.photoURL   = authData.photoURL
        this.roles      = { reader: true }
    }
}
```

The payload id gets printed in console, but 'data' is shown undefined.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you give us your data structure?

Comment: Added the data structure for 'User', but I don't feel thats the problem. The missing 'data' object is actually part of the [AngularFire2 library](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#the-documentchangeaction-type), so it should exist. What I notice is that in the 'snapshot' variable is of type Action<any>, when it ideally should have been DocumentChangeAction.

Comment: Correct use is: `snapshot.payload.val();`

Comment: I think val() is for the realtime database. I'm using firestore.